# Managed package class that implements Schedulable interface disappeared from selection popup after Summer 15 preview upgrade

Tags: apex, visualforce, schedulebatch

We have managed package that has global class implementing Schedulable interface (API 29.0). We could select this class under Apex Classes - > Schedule Apex while scheduling job in org where package is installed. After this org was upgraded with Summer 15 release preview past weekend class cannot be found in this popup even after search by exact name. System Administrator profile has this class enabled under Security page.

I wonder if anyone has faced with the same issue and if there are any ideas to resolve?

Thanks

Comment: If nothing else has changed in the environment, this is probably a bug and you'll need to reach out to Salesforce support to get it logged / corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After submitting case to SF and some time passed it appeared back again.